# NodeJs Kafka producer not able to send messages

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am a beginner with Kafka, I am trying to produce messages to Kafka producer which is on Confluent cloud. But somehow my producer instance fails to create or some issue is happening there which I am not able to understand. Here is my proucer.js code (this is the sample code on Confluent website):

```
/* Copyright 2020 Confluent Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * =============================================================================
 *
 * Produce messages to Confluent Cloud
 * Using the node-rdkafka client for Apache Kafka
 *
 * =============================================================================
 */ 

const Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');
const { configFromCli } = require('./config');

const ERR_TOPIC_ALREADY_EXISTS = 36;

function ensureTopicExists(config) {
  const adminClient = Kafka.AdminClient.create({
    'bootstrap.servers': config['bootstrap.servers'],
    'sasl.username': config['sasl.username'],
    'sasl.password': config['sasl.password'],
    'security.protocol': config['security.protocol'],
    'sasl.mechanisms': config['sasl.mechanisms']
  });

  console.log("admin client initiated")

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    adminClient.createTopic({
      topic: config.topic,
      num_partitions: 1,
      replication_factor: 3
    }, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(`Created topic ${config.topic}`);
        return resolve();
      }

      if (err.code === ERR_TOPIC_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        return resolve();
      }

      return reject(err);
    });
  });
}

function createProducer(config, onDeliveryReport) {
  const producer = new Kafka.Producer({
    'bootstrap.servers': config['bootstrap.servers'],
    'sasl.username': config['sasl.username'],
    'sasl.password': config['sasl.password'],
    'security.protocol': config['security.protocol'],
    'sasl.mechanisms': config['sasl.mechanisms'],    
    'dr_msg_cb': true
  });

  console.log("received producer config");
  console.log(producer);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    producer
      .on('ready', () => resolve(producer))
      .on('delivery-report', onDeliveryReport)
      .on('event.error', (err) => {
        console.log('event.error', err);
        reject(err);
      });
    producer.connect();
  });
}

async function produceExample() {
  const config = await configFromCli();

  console.log("received config");

  if (config.usage) {
    return console.log(config.usage);
  }

  console.log("received config usage");

  //await ensureTopicExists(config);

  console.log("topic created");
  console.log(config.topic);

  const producer = await createProducer(config, (err, report) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error producing', err)
    } else {
      console.log("producing");
      const {topic, partition, value} = report;
      console.log(`Successfully produced record to topic "${topic}" partition ${partition} ${value}`);
    }
  });

  console.log("producer started");

  for (let idx = 0; idx < 10; ++idx) {
    const key = 'alice';
    const value = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ count: idx }));

    console.log(`Producing record ${key}\t${value}`);

    producer.produce(config.topic, -1, value, key);
  }

  producer.flush(10000, () => {
    producer.disconnect();
  });
}

produceExample()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Something went wrong:\n${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

This is my config.js file:

```
/* Copyright 2020 Confluent Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

const minimist = require('minimist');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

// cli config

const title = "Example Node.js Confluent Cloud client";

const requiredOpts = [
  ['config', '--config CONFIG', 'C:\Users\username\.confluent\nodejs.config'] 
  ,['topic', '--topic TOPIC', 'test1']
];

const requiredConfig = [
  ['bootstrap.servers', 'bootstrap.servers=<host1:port1...>', 'Your Confluent Cloud cluster bootstrap server(s). Separate multiple host/port pairs with commas.'],
  ['sasl.username', 'sasl.username=<string>', 'Your Confluent Cloud API key'],
  ['sasl.password', 'sasl.password=<string>', 'Your Confluent Cloud API secret'],
];

const alias = {
  t: 'topic',
  f: 'config'
};

exports.configFromCli = async function(args = process.argv.slice(2)) {
  const opts = minimist(args, { alias });
  const missingOpts = requiredOpts.filter(([k]) => !opts.hasOwnProperty(k));
  
  if (missingOpts.length) {
    console.log("some configurations missing");
    return {
      ...opts,
      usage: usage('Some required arguments were not provided:', missingOpts)
    };
  }

  const config = await configFromPath(opts.config);
  const missingConfig = requiredConfig.filter(([k]) => !config.hasOwnProperty(k));

  if (missingConfig.length) {
    console.log("missing configurations");
    return {
      ...opts,
      ...config,
      usage: usage('Some required configuration values were not provided:', missingConfig)
    };
  }

  console.log("returning configurations");
  return { ...opts, ...config };
};

function usage(heading, missing) {
  const hints = missing.map(([,pattern,desc]) => `    ${pattern}
    ${desc}`);

      return `${title}

${heading}
${hints.join('\n\n')}
`;
}

// config file access and parsing

function readAllLines(path) {    
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Test file access directly, so that we can fail fast.
    // Otherwise, an ENOENT is thrown in the global scope by the readline internals.
    try {
      fs.accessSync(path, fs.constants.R_OK);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    
    let lines = [];
    
    const reader = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(path),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    
    reader
      .on('line', (line) => lines.push(line))
      .on('close', () => resolve(lines));
  });
}

async function configFromPath(path) {
  const lines = await readAllLines(path);

  return lines
    .filter((line) => !/^\s*?#/.test(line))
    .map((line) => line
      .split('=')
      .map((s) => s.trim()))
    .reduce((config, [k, v]) => {
      config[k] = v;
      return config;
    }, {});
};
```

Following is the output I am getting:

```
    node producer.js -f C:/Users/username/.confluent/nodejs.config -t test1
    returning configurations
    received config
    received config usage
    topic created
    test1
    received producer config
<producer specs suppressed>
```

Someone please let me know what else needs to be done here to successfully produce messages using this code?

**Update:**

The above code will just work fine if the username and password are provided without any quotes in the config file.